# Is it possible to have a Java Stream with intermediate producers?

Tags: java, tree, java-stream

I have a parser which traverses a tree recursevly. I would like rewrite the implementation of this parser in such a way that I can use the Stream API of Java and only the Stream API without any recursion.

Each node of the tree should be processed by a processor with the following signature: `Stream<Token> process(Token)`. IMHO *I cannot* use `flatMap()` because I don't know the depth of the tree I process and I can't modify the stream I process. I know how to do this with normal loop, a simple list and a lot of index and offset computation.

Comment: It would be still good to look at the normal for loop implementation and find out the line of code in present attempt where you are facing the issue.

Comment: Normally, the *starting point* is a stream of tokens, whereas the result of the parsing is a single composed object, like an AST. Producing more tokens out of a single token, like your `Stream<Token> process(Token)` signature suggests, makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand clearly:

1. you want a stream of all nodes in your tree. Is that correct ?
2. You've got a `process` function giving you back direct children of a node

If that's right, and you really want to exclude any recursion, [Spliterator API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html) is the way to go. You create a stream flavored iterator to sink elements in a stream. Any standard Java Stream uses a Spliterator under the hood.

**EDIT**: See implementation provided at the end of code Example (depth-first browsing).

However, if you allow recursion, it becomes easy to produce a depth-first stream.
Simple example below shows both approaches :

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class Main {

    /**
     * Sample in-memory node class
     */
    static class Node {
        Node[] children;
        final String name;

        Node(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Simple implementation of your process function, giving back direct children.
     * @param node Node to get children for.
     * @return A stream of available children, can be empty.
     */
    static Stream<Node> process(Node node) {
        return node.children == null? Stream.empty() : Arrays.stream(node.children);
    }

    /**
     * Recursion entrypoint. Allow to perform depth-first browsing.
     */
    static Stream<Node> recurse(Node input) {
        if (input.children == null || input.children.length < 1) return Stream.of(input);
        else return Stream.concat(
                Stream.of(input),
                Arrays.stream(input.children)
                        .flatMap(Main::recurse)
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        /* Simple tree :
         * ROOT
         * - A
         * -- AA
         * -- AB
         * --- ABA
         * -- AC
         * - B
         * -- BA
         * -- BB
         * - C
         */
        Node root = new Node("ROOT");
        Node a = new Node("A");
        Node b = new Node("B");
        Node c = new Node("C");
        root.children = new Node[]{a, b, c};

        Node aa = new Node("AA");
        Node ab = new Node("AB");
        Node ac = new Node("AC");
        a.children = new Node[]{aa, ab, ac};

        Node ba = new Node("BA");
        Node bb = new Node("BB");
        b.children = new Node[]{ba, bb};

        Node aba = new Node("ABA");
        ab.children = new Node[]{aba};

        System.out.println("RECURSIVE BROWSING");
        Stream.of(root).flatMap(Main::recurse)
                .forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println("NON-RECURSIVE USING SINGLE-THREAD SPLITERATOR");
        final NodeSpliterator spliterator = new NodeSpliterator(root);
        StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, false)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    static class NodeSpliterator implements Spliterator<Node> {

        private final Stack<Node> nodeQueue = new Stack<>();

        NodeSpliterator(Node root) {
            nodeQueue.push(root);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super Node> action) {
            if (nodeQueue.empty()) return false; // No more nodes, end of this fork of the stream.
            final Node next = nodeQueue.pop();
            // Iterate on next available node
            action.accept(next);
            // Sink direct children for next iteration
            final int endOfQueue = nodeQueue.size();
            process(next).forEach(node -> nodeQueue.add(endOfQueue, node));
            // Notify Stream API that an element has successfully been processed.
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public Spliterator<Node> trySplit() {
            // Little trick : Parallelism of ordered streams requires the fork to distribute a prefix of
            // Available elements. I'll keep things simple here, I let you work on that.
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long estimateSize() {
            return Long.MAX_VALUE; // Would require external metadata for estimation, or womplete browsing for exact count
        }

        @Override
        public int characteristics() {
            // Note : you can add Spliterator.CONCURRENT below once you've resolved how to implement trySplit.
            return ORDERED|NONNULL;
        }
    }
}
```

This code produces following output:

```
RECURSIVE BROWSING
ROOT
A
AA
AB
ABA
AC
B
BA
BB
C
NON-RECURSIVE USING SINGLE-THREAD SPLITERATOR
ROOT
A
AA
AB
ABA
AC
B
BA
BB
C
```

Comment: The OP said he couldn't use `flatmap`

Comment: @WJS I guess the OP was mistaken there? It seems to work.

Comment: Well, he states that recursive approach is not desired , an using flat map, we *kind of* use recursive solution. Nonetheless, I've provided another solution without *flatmap*, based on a spliterator.